# I'm getting a Spark error while running AWS Glue Job locally in windows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I need to run Glue Job in my local machine. So followed some documentation to run a glue job without using docker. So I had to install few dependencies like apache maven and spark. I followed these documentations [[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-using-etl-library), [[2]](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-setup-aws-gluepyspark-job-development-environment-akhilesh-singh/)but still it's throwing below error.

```
warnings.warn(
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3502)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3527)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:2112)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethodsByNameAndLength(ReflectionEngine.java:345)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:305)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\clientserver.py", line 516, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
  File "C:\Testing Works\aws-glue-libs\main.py", line 14, in <module>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
  File "C:\Testing Works\aws-glue-libs\awsglue\context.py", line 64, in __init__
        ... 13 more
    self.spark_session = SparkSession(sparkContext, self._glue_scala_context.getSparkSession())
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 334, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o28.getSparkSession
PS C:\Testing Works\aws-glue-libs> SUCCESS: The process with PID 11708 (child process of PID 3416) has been terminated.
ERROR: The process with PID 3416 (child process of PID 25788) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
ERROR: The process with PID 25788 (child process of PID 11356) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance

EDIT:
source code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
...
```